# Installing newer version of lsblk to RHEL

Tags: linux, rhel, package-management, yum, util-linux

I am trying to install newer version of lsblk to `Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.6`. I have installed `util-linux` on my system in version `util-linux.x86_64-2.23.2-59.el7_6.1` but due to a compatibility issue i need to have `lsblk` at teast on version `2.27.1`
Unfortunatelly Red Hat does not privide newer package of `util-linux`. I have tried to search `epel` repository with no success. Is there any way to install newer version of `lsblk` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the third-party package manager [Nix](https://nixos.org/nix/) to install a newer version of util-linux.

In fact, to avoid any potential compatibility issues with the rest of RHEL 7.6, I recommend running your application within a Nix environment which contains the newer util-linux. In other words, I recommend using `nix-shell` over `nix-env`. For example, after installing Nix you can run `nix-shell -p utillinux` to enter a shell which contains a newer version of util-linux. Outside of said shell the RHEL util-linux would be available.